# Create a record in another table when a record is created in first table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a two tables, whenever a record is inserted in service field, I would like to automatically create a record in payment field. Can someone guide me on how to achieve this? I am a beginner in sql.

`Service` `Payment`

Service field:

```
id
vin
mechanic_id
start_date
end_date
payment_id
```

payment field:

```
id
service_id
total
payment_date
```

Comment: can you provide some code on how you created the tables and maybe some examples of what you want to do, and what softwares you are using

Comment: Straight off you want to create a trigger for on create and a trigger for on update.

Comment: @Monofuse , but where are triggers defined in postgres? How do I make sure the trigger will run when I add the record?

Comment: Well you could create some demo tables and and run an insert / update query against them to check. As to where they are defined, the documentation is pretty clear about this: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/sql-createtrigger.html

Answer (score 0):

You must study triggers in PostgreSQL for automatic record creation when some action happens in SQL.